# How can I make my MVC5 ASP.NET Identity login action check if a user name exists?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am using the MVC5 login Identity authentication code below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Validate the password
            IdentityResult result = IdentityManager.Authentication.CheckPasswordAndSignIn(AuthenticationManager, model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe);
            if (result.Success)
            {
                return Redirect("~/home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

The code gives a message if the password is not correct but if the username does not exist it gives the same message saying "Incorrect password."

Does anyone out there have a solution that also does a check for the username existing and gives a correct message if it does not exist ? Note that I am using ASP.Net Identity so it would need to be a solution for this and not for the Simple Membership authentication

Comment: For reference it is usually considered bad practice now to give a message more specific than "Incorrect username or password" as simply confirming the existence of an account with a given username can be helpful to those attempting to hack the application.

Answer (score 3):

If you update to the 1.0 RTM Identity packages, you can check if a user exists by:
`UserManager.FindByName("username")`

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and will continue to check it out. Can you tell me will the stable release date for the 1.0 be the same as VS2013 release date?